# Paw re-encodes URL values

Tags: paw-app

I need to request the following URL:

```
http://myhost.com/api/v3/projects/digitalis%2Fbackend/issues
```

but this URL is being sent:

```
http://myhost.com/api/v3/projects/digitalis%252Fbackend/issues
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Preferences (Paw menu), tab "HTTP" and uncheck "Re-encode Percent Escapes". It should be working fine.

[image: Disable Percent Escapes in Paw]

Comment: This is unchecked by default but PAW is still encoding the URL when I don't want it to alter it. I have a url that includes '.../#/...' and the # is converted to a %23 which causes it to fail.

Comment: @FuadKamal yes we have a known encoding bug (too many characters are percent encoded, when they shouldn't be), it will be fixed in the next version.

Comment: any chance we can get beta access? :P

Comment: we don't have a proper beta mechanism yet, but we will release this bugfix in a week...